# Which order do these dimensions go in

Tags: air-travel, kuwait

23 x 36 x 56cm

On the Kuwait website it says that hand luggage cannot exceed 115cm.
What is the order of the dimension, is it length x width x height ?

Comment: Usually length > width > height.

Comment: It does not really matter, as long as you turn your luggage correct, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means:

```
Length + Height + width
```

[image: luggage]

The total of that should not exceed the allowed size. In your case it is 115 cm. BTW that's called *linear length*.